# phpmyadmin not installing correctly on server

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

In my client's server the phpmyadmin not installed .

So client ask us to install that.

I refer this link to install phpmyadmin:

http://www.thewebhostinghero.com/tutorials/wamp-phpmyadmin.html

I downloaded and uploaded the phpmyadmin into server .

This is the server path where the phpmyadmin folder is installed:

```
/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/mysitefolder/phpMyAdmin
```

Then i created a folder in phhpmyadmin as `config` and set `permission 777`.

then i take the url in browser as:

```
http://mysite.com/phpMyAdmin/setup/index.php
```

I entered the mysql host ,usernmae,password and also changed the `authentication type` as `config`.

But the config.inc.php file not created in config folder.

EDIT:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the config.sample.inc.php file and rename it config.inc.php and do the changes in that file by hand.

Comment: can you be a bit more specific about the errors and the warning?

Comment: You need to fill in a random String (secret passphrase) for the variable $cfg['blowfish_secret']. Also your file(s) probably are utf-8 encoded, but the mbstring extension of your php is not installed and the mcrypt extension is also not installed... how to install extensions is another chapter, please first search the web for guidance... make sure you know which php version you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

I know you from the last problem you have a linux distribution. Use the repositories.

```
apt-get install mysql-server
apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Comment: he's on windows! 'wamp-phpmyadmin'

Comment: Isn't the phpmyadmin version he downloaded for windows, but he is actually on linux? The path he uses would suggest so...

Comment: @ m7o, i got my mistake...it is linux server ...so what i do?i have no shell access

Comment: @ stony, i have no shell access

Comment: @ Stony, do you have any idea...?